# How can I filter on a nullable DateTime field using EF4.1?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4.1, nullable

I have a table with a nullable DateTime field:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[myTable](
  [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
  ...
  [FinishedDate] [datetime] NULL,
  etc...
```

When I try this:

```
var activeThings = from foo in _context.myTable
                   where foo.FinishedDate == null
                   select foo;

foreach ( var thing in activeThings ) {
   ... do some stuff ...
}
```

I get no values back.  How can I filter this on null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var activeThings = from foo in _context.myTable
                   where !foo.FinishedDate.HasValue //foo.FinishedDate.HasValue==false
                   select foo;
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sksw8094.aspx)

HasValue return boolean,

is true => not null

is false => null